# Laravel Passport invalid JWT token

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I have created a Laravel application with multiple Passport APIs. Several external applications (such as a mobile application, for example) connect to the Laravel / Passport API. And I frequently receive Sentry errors on these various API calls with the following trace:

`League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request.`

`Lcobucci\JWT\Token\InvalidTokenStructure: The JWT string must have two dots.`

What is very strange is that this bug occurs very frequently, but most of the time, the API routes work perfectly. I have absolutely no idea how to resolve this bug since I'm simply using Passport to connect, and I'm obviously not concerned with the possible format of JWT tokens...

Laravel v.9

Passport v.10

Comment: And what token you pass to request when error appear? Normal token, as usual?

Comment: error message "The JWT string must have two dots" indicates that the JWT you're receiving doesn't have the expected structure

Comment: @Maksim I use absolute normal tokens.